# How to save multiple items in a ListView into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My code works only for the first item but it doesn't work for the multiple items. How best I be helped?

```vb
Public Sub saveItemListview(lstview As ListView)
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.StockConnectionString)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        sql = "insert into salestb values(@items,@quantity,@price)"

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

        For Each item As ListViewItem In lstview.Items
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", item.Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.SubItems(1).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", item.SubItems(2).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Next

        MsgBox("Saved successfully")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub saveItemListview(lstview As ListView)
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.StockConnectionString)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        sql = "insert into salestb values(@items,@quantity,@price)"

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

        For Each item As ListViewItem In lstview.Items
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", item.Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.SubItems(1).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", item.SubItems(2).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Next

        MsgBox("Save Successsfully")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If I tried the multiple items, it gives an error message as:

> The variable name '@items' is already declared. Variable name must always be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: So many people misuse the `ListView` control.  Don't use it as a grid.  It isn't one.  You should be using a `DataGridView` and you should be binding a `DataTable` to it.  You can then save all the data with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter.  You can populate the `DataTable` or just build the schema using the data adapter too, by calling `Fill` or `FillSchema`.

Comment: You need to call _cmd.Parameters.Clear_ before adding again the parameters. But a better option is to create the parameters outside the loop with dummy values and inside the loop set the Value property with the actual data

Comment: @Steve, there's no need for dummy values.  You just create the parameters with no values, which you do by calling `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`.  `AddWithValue` is a bad idea anyway, because it can infer an inappropriate data type.

Comment: @Steve, i added _cmd.parameters.Clear_ and worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub saveItemListview(lstview As ListView)
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.StockConnectionString)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        sql = "insert into salestb values(@items,@quantity,@price)"

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

        For Each item As ListViewItem In lstview.Items
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", item.Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.SubItems(1).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", item.SubItems(2).Text.ToString.Trim)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd.Parameter.clear()
        Next

        MsgBox("Save Successsfully")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Pure-code answers are usually not very helpful. Please edit your post, add a paragraph which relates the code to the question, explain what you did and why, and in far this is a solution.